# C# Downloading a zip file from url based on input params

Tags: c#, download, http-post

I have a requirement where I have to download a zip file using c# (size can vary between 10mb - 400mb) from server based on input params. For example, download reports for userId = 10 and year = 2012. 
The webserver accepts these two params and returns a zip file.  How can I achieve this using WebClient class? 
Thanks

Comment: what have u tried so far?

Comment: For that size i would use httpwebrequest/ socket to implement functions like download resume

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a 'give me teh codez' type site. You are expected to do your own research and ask a question when you encounter a problem.

Comment: first question I would ask is what are the QueryString params what does the URL look like based on Baris answer I would say he is almost correct but he would need to pass the querystring in the url then that url should be built based on what the parameters are correct me if my understanding is wrong.. something like this work `Uri url = new Uri("http://www.microsoft.com/windows8.zip").
          AddQuery("userid", @someUserId).
          AddQuery("year", @someyear);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do so by extending the WebClient class

```
class ExtWebClient : WebClient
    {

        public NameValueCollection PostParam { get; set; }

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            WebRequest tmprequest = base.GetWebRequest(address);

            HttpWebRequest request = tmprequest as HttpWebRequest;

            if (request != null && PostParam != null && PostParam.Count > 0)
            {
                StringBuilder postBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                request.Method = "POST";
                //build the post string

                for (int i = 0; i < PostParam.Count; i++)
                {
                    postBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", Uri.EscapeDataString(PostParam.GetKey(i)),
                                             Uri.EscapeDataString(PostParam.Get(i)));
                    if (i < PostParam.Count - 1)
                    {
                        postBuilder.Append("&");
                    }
                }
                byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postBuilder.ToString());
                request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                var stream = request.GetRequestStream();
                stream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
                stream.Close();
                stream.Dispose();

            }

            return tmprequest;
        }
    }
```

Usage : in case u have to create POST type request

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        ExtWebClient webclient = new ExtWebClient();
        webclient.PostParam = new NameValueCollection();
        webclient.PostParam["param1"] = "value1";
        webclient.PostParam["param2"] = "value2";

        webclient.DownloadFile("http://www.example.com/myfile.zip", @"C:\myfile.zip");
    }
}
```

Usage : for GET type request, u can simply use the Normal webclient

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        WebClient webclient = new WebClient();

        webclient.DownloadFile("http://www.example.com/myfile.zip?param1=value1&param2=value2", @"C:\myfile.zip");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solutions works perfectly. While using HttpWebrequest I was able to download stream but unable to save it in file. and while using webclient I was not able to set request type as Post. Your solution combines both.

Comment: You saved my life! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
string url = @"http://www.microsoft.com/windows8.zip";

WebClient client = new WebClient();

    client.DownloadFileCompleted +=    new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);

    client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), @"c:\windows\windows8.zip");


void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("File downloaded");
}
```

Comment: he needs to download file via post parameter, default is GET

Comment: oh, ok. he must create a reports page etc. and this page accept parameters then return releated files.